# dynamic positions of UI-elements within a Scrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview with some labels and a UIButton within it.

The problem i'm facing is that the UIButton is staying at the same position, 
What i'd like is for the uibutton to follow it's initial position and always stay in the top-right
even if i scroll the scrollview down.

```
--------------------------------------
-                      ---------------
-                      -  uibutton   -
-                      ---------------
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
-                                    -
--------------------------------------
```

So, how can i programmatically state that the button should always be fixed in the upper-Right position of the CURRENT showed part of the scrollview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont put button inside the scroll view .... put it in super view of scrollView

Comment: Yeah amit is right... put it in the super view not in the scroll view...

Comment: Why don't you put the button outside of your scrollView ?(I don't mean to be harsh , just a suggestion).

Comment: Ok, so how do i go about adding it to the superview of scrollview?

Comment: Our scrollview will cover the entire screen on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by having the `UIButton` outside the `scrollview`.

Done with the following lines...

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height-100)];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height+however_big_area_i_needed);
```

The button was made using IB.